# how to setup test and production environment for apple iap server-to-server notification

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store, subscription

I want apple send purchase notification of real user to my production environment after the app is published.

And meanwhile, i need apple to send purchase notification of sandbox test account to my test environment.

However, i can only config one URL in apple connect from apple iap server-to-server notification.

I try to receive notification in my production environment, and parse the payload of the notification, if it is a notification of sandbox, then deliver it to test environment. but i do not think this is a good way, because my test environment rely on my production environment.

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The App Store does not provide URLs for different environments. You have to check the environment field of the message received from the App Store with your own single server, distinguish whether it is for test or production, and send it back to each server.

Quoted from Apple docs:

```
If you enabled App Store server notifications for your app, test your logic for
transactions in the sandbox environment. To determine if a notification for a 
subscription event occurred in the test environment, check whether the value of 
the environment field in the server-to-server JSON responseBody object equals 
Sandbox.
```